# why use MAT_DIALOG_DATA to pass data to angular material dialogs

Tags: angular, angular-material

in the documentation they use `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` to share data with a component.

However, why not just go `ref.componentInstance.myInput = my_value`
What's the difference between passing data to a component versus setting the component instances inputs? I haven't found any limitations of just setting values on the component directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`, the data is available in the component's constructor and can be used for proper initialization of class fields.

After creating a component by calling its constructor, Angular calls its [lifecycle hook methods](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) (i.e. `ngOnInit`), each at specific moments.

`MatDialog.open` returns a reference to the newly-opened dialog even before Angular is calling any life-cycle hook of its component. If you pass data using that reference immediately after calling `MatDialog.open`, there's no other difference compared to providing the data using `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`. If however asynchronous processing is involved between opening the dialog and setting the data, the result  is unpredictable since life-cycle hook methods may be called when the component data is not available yet.

Comment: just want to say - really great answer - exactly what I wanted to know thanks